# How to prevent user from uncheck all checks from a group of checkboxes inputs with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hello I am using a group of checkboxes to filter data from a feed, basically I am setting all the checkboxes to be active by default, how can I prevent the user from unchecking all the options? I need at least one to be checked. Hope someone can help.

I created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7Lopj4hf/1/)

This is my html:

```
<div class="pull-left" id="filter">
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">

        <label class="btn btn-primary active" id="btnOne">
            <input type="checkbox" name="filter"> One Selected
        </label>

        <label class="btn btn-primary active" id="btnTwo">
            <input type="checkbox" name="filter"> Two Selected
        </label>

        <label class="btn btn-primary active" id="btnThree">
            <input type="checkbox" name="filter"> Three Selected
        </label>

        <label class="btn btn-primary active" id="btnFour">
            <input type="checkbox" name="filter"> Four Selected
        </label>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure because you using bootstrap (don't have experience with it) - are checkboxes automatically checked on load, or just buttons have 'active' class ?

Comment: Only the buttons have class "active", I am thinking is better to check for that, something like if last item has class active.. prevent the click?

Answer (score 2):

Add this code to the javascript, [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7Lopj4hf/2/)

```
$(function() {
  $(".btn.active").click(function(){
      if($(this).hasClass('active')){
          if($(".btn.active").length===1){
              return false;     
          }
    }
  });
});
```

Note that you are not changing the checkboxes `checked` attribute, you are using the buttons with the `active` class toggle behavior of bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

The best alternative is to use `radio buttons` instead of `checkboxes`.

I find the change event more reliable and I would prevent user from unchecking all checkboxes like so:

```
$(':checkbox[name=filter]').on('change', function() {
    $(':checkbox[name=filter]:checked').length == 0 
    && !this.checked 
    && $(this).prop('checked', true);
});
```

```js
$(function() {
    $(':checkbox[name=filter]').on('change', function() {
        $(':checkbox[name=filter]:checked').length == 0 && !this.checked && $(this).prop('checked', true);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pull-left" id="filter">
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">

        <label class="btn btn-primary active" id="btnOne">
            <input type="checkbox" name="filter"> One Selected
        </label>

        <label class="btn btn-primary active" id="btnTwo">
            <input type="checkbox" name="filter"> Two Selected
        </label>

        <label class="btn btn-primary active" id="btnThree">
            <input type="checkbox" name="filter"> Three Selected
        </label>

        <label class="btn btn-primary active" id="btnFour">
            <input type="checkbox" name="filter"> Four Selected
        </label>

    </div>
</div>
```